# set all href value automaticly

Tags: javascript, html, href

This doesn't work. I want to set all links with no href value to javascript:void(0) automatically on external js...

```
var hLink=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i=0;i<hLink.length;i++) { 
  if (hLink[i].getAttribute('href')==null) { 
    hLink[i].setAttribute('href','javascript:void(0)');
  }
}
```

Comment: People will be much more inclined to help you if you post code such that it is readable.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Its a little different from forums. please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0; i<anchors.length; i++ ) {
  if( !anchors[i].href ) {
      anchors[i].href = 'javascript:void(0)';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the href attribute is not set, I can't remember if `getAttribute('href')` returns `null` or `''` (an empty string). In fact, it may depend on the browser. I would change your `if` statement to:

```
if (!hLink[i].getAttribute('href'))
```

since `null` and `''` are both [falsy values](http://blog.nydd.org/2008/12/falsy-values-%E2%80%9Cjavascript-the-good-parts%E2%80%9D/), you're covered either way.